# How to stop adding values together when using while loop

Tags: python

Here, i want issue the exact amount of notes of related denominations.  but when the loop moving to next (Ex:1500 to 1000) the two values will be added in to together how can I correct it?

---

```
Note = [1500,1000,800,1200,900,600,1300,1400,760,780]
noteo = [1000,500,100,50,20,10,5,2,1]

n = len(Note)
i = 0

note1000=note500=note100=note50=note20=note10=note5=note2=note1=0

while i < n:
 amt=int(Note[i]) 
 if amt>=1000:
    note1000=amt//1000
    amt=amt-note1000*1000
 if amt>=500:
    note500=amt//500
    amt=amt-note500*500
 if amt>=100:
    note100=amt//100
    amt=amt-note100*100
 if amt>=50:
    note50=amt//50
    amt=amt-note50*50
 if amt>=20:
    note20=amt//20
    amt=amt-note20*20
 if amt>=10:
    note10=amt//10
    amt=amt-note10*10
 if amt>=5:
    note5=amt//5
    amt=amt-note5*5
 if amt>=2:
    note2=amt//2
    amt=amt-note2*2
 if amt>=1:
    note1=amt//1
    amt=amt-note1*1 
 print(Note[i],"\t= \t",note1000,note500,note100,note50,note20,note10,note5,note2,note1)
 i += 1
```

---

This is how i got the output

[image: This is how i got the output]

Comment: Use `elif` instead of `if` for mutually-exclusive conditions.

Comment: Why doesn't your script use the `noteo` list?

Comment: amt = 1000 will trigger all conditions. You must use `elif`

Comment: Can u explain, for 1000rs => output is  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0?

Comment: Instead of lots of `if` statements for the different note values, loop through `noteo`. When you find the note that matches, do the calculation and then break out of the loop.

Comment: @ShivamSeth That's the problem they're trying to fix. That output is wrong.

Comment: Move `note1000=note500=note100=note50=note20=note10=note5=note2=note1=0` inside  while loop

Comment: Instead of 9 different variables, use a dictionary whose keys are the note values.

Answer (score 0):

The code with those many `if`s looks confusing to me. I'd go completely without if. Just a `for` and a `while` loop are sufficient:

```
#!/bin/python

amt0 = 1275    # starting amount
note_values = [1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1]

# define helping variables
note_counts = [0] * len(note_values)
amt = amt0

# all the magic of counting the notes is here
for i in range(0, len(note_counts)):
  while amt >= note_values[i]:
    note_counts[i] += 1
    amt -= note_values[i]

# now try to output the result
print("Amount "+str(amt0))
print(str(note_values))
print(str(note_counts))
```

You may still want to improve the output format.

Comment: amt = amt0;   (remove the semicolon)

Comment: Sorry. Too much of Java... ;-)